# Angular ui grid (ng-grid) 3: showHeader isn't changing anything

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm playing around with this angular plugin.
Here's my issue - I'm setting the grid with no headers as default. When I want to set the grid header back, it doesn't work by changing the gridOptions.showHeader attribute.
Here's my toggle code (I've added the refresh() once I saw it doesn't work without it but the refresh() doesn't help as well):

```
  $scope.toggleHeader = function(){
    $scope.gridOptions.showHeader = !$scope.gridOptions.showHeader;  
    $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
  }
```

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eEzSH5hKUTZFbkxiruSt

Anyway to toggle the grid's header on and off?

EDIT: In order to show the motivation of such a change, I've modified my code a bit to use watchers on some gridStatus variable (which could be anything - in my case it's minimize):

http://plnkr.co/edit/1fX6ZuqUt7xANO1P7MMG

Comment: Not sure ui-grid support gridOptions refresh, but definitely possible with css.

Answer (score 0):

A number of the gridOptions aren't dynamic - they're set on initialisation and then not re-evaluated.  This is part of the aim of the grid to minimise the number of watchers (and therefore maximise performance)  Refer: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1819

The short answer is that you can't easily change this once the grid renders - you either have a grid with headers or one without.  You can, however, re-render the grid.  The easiest way to do this is to put an ng-if on your grid directive, and then toggle it, which would look something like:

`<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ng-if="refresh"></div>`

and

  `function refreshGrid() {
    $scope.refresh = false;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.refresh = true;
    });
  };`

Comment: This looks a bit cumbersome.  Shouldn't that be a part of what the "refresh" function does? 
I mean, that are various refresh functions in the api (queueGridRefresh(), queueRefresh(), refresh() and then again for columns and rows etc.). Why not make one of them just re-render the grid or create a new one just for the headers?

Comment: Another drawback of this is that using "ng-if" might create a $compile:ctreq error from angular in some cases.

Comment: Short answer - because that's not what it does, and there are only a handful of devs on the project who are quite occupied with the bugs we already have.  The refresh is used internally in a bunch of situations, and those situations aren't targeted at redrawing the entire grid.  There is a notifyDataChange architecture which can do dynamic options, and over time we are adding options to that, but it takes a bit of time and fiddling around.