# Is it possible to remove row header column from angular ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, rowheader

I want to show and hide row header column in angular ui-grid, on button click. Now I can add row header column using addRowHeaderColumn method from gridApi core. But I don't see any method to remove it (or hide it). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

showHeader:false in latest version in ui-grid

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This did not worked, however it leaded me to answer which worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455298/angular-ui-grid-ng-grid-3-showheader-isnt-changing-anything