# Is it possible to remove one row header column from angular ui-grid?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I had checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074605/is-it-possible-to-remove-row-header-column-from-angular-ui-grid).

That's a clever idea but isn't for my problem.

My grid has a row number header column and some other row header columns,
and these is a switch for only the row number column.
How could I remove only row number column when it exists?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a way to do that:

```
var numColIndex = _.findIndex(gridApi.grid.columns, (c) => c.name === numColDef.name);
if (numColIndex >= 0)
    gridApi.grid.columns.splice(0, 1);
```